# How to convert CChar audio buffer into AVAudioPCMBuffer?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, audiobuffer, avaudiopcmbuffer

I'm working on `ZoomMeetingSDK` integration for my Mac app. SDK streams audio buffers once a user joins the meeting. I'm trying to convert these audio buffers into `AVAudioPCMBuffer` so that i can generate a live transcripts by leveraging `SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest`.

Audio buffer object I'm receiving from zoomSDK.

```
@interface ZoomSDKAudioRawData : NSObject
-(BOOL)canAddRef;
-(BOOL)addRef;
-(int)releaseData;
-(char*)getBuffer;
-(unsigned int)getBufferLen;
-(unsigned int)getSampleRate;
-(unsigned int)getChannelNum;
@end
```

`ZoomSDKAudioRawData.getBuffer()` is in `UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>?` type, I need to generate `AVAudioPCMBuffer` type using this buffer and few other properties that ZoomSDKAudioRawData has. ZoomSDKAudioRawData [documentation](https://marketplacefront.zoom.us/sdk/meeting/macos/interface_zoom_s_d_k_audio_raw_data.html).

Also [Zoom mentions](https://developers.zoom.us/docs/meeting-sdk/macos/raw-data/#raw-data-formats) that Audio streams are in PCM format. so i assume this can be convertible into `AVAudioPCMBuffer`. Can someone help me solve this?